# CLI to monitor connection pool in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, istio

I have used Istio's circuitbreaker settings that ejects a host from connection pool based on number of consecutive errors. Is there a way to monitor the connection pool using command line and see the changes to host id or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line tool, I'm not sure. But the load-balancing pool size is stored in Envoy metrics (see membership healthy / total and outlier detection stats: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/cluster_manager/cluster_stats#health-check-statistics ). So, if you have istio's prometheus running, you can open its UI and view the values (or `curl` it with prometheus rest api).

Example of metric name:
`envoy_cluster_inbound_8080__my_service_my_namespace_svc_cluster_local_membership_healthy`

Where 8080 is the port of your service, `my_service` is its name, `my_namespace` its namespace. There's also a similiar one for outbound: `envoy_cluster_outbound_(etc.)`

In Istio 1.1 these metrics are reorganized into a format more suitable for Prometheus, so the names change a little bit and service name / namespace become label instead of being part of the name.

Note that Kiali ( https://www.kiali.io/ ) shows this health information.